# how to bypass login authentication when sending password link by email asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, security, query-string

> i am sending the email of the user in Query string(encrypted).
>   http://localhost:51266/User/User_EditPassword.aspxaccesstype=email&te=U0hSbllMUjFNbHlKR3RvUjB3OUgvK1FSdHVacmkzUFpQK1ZrYmg5YlYvV0t3eklwaTlPTjYrV1V3KzJTN1pWSw==
>
> but when i click on the link it gives me msg."**u can't access the
>   page**" so how can i access the

`User_EditPassword.aspx`

> page so that user can change the password without login  to the system
>   ?

Comment: if you want a valid query string then there should at least be an `?` after `.aspx` so it should look like `.aspx?accesstype=email`. Also, with lack of information we cannot help you. What do you use for authentication? how do you generate the token? There are tons of possibilities.

Comment: Are you using Forms Authentication?

Comment: yes @msd using them only

Answer (score 2):

For Implementing a Password Reset mechanism you've to take care of a couple of things. Personally I prefer using the follow approach:

1. A user requests a new password.
2. In the client-side If the user exists or not show the User the
   same message ex: "An email will be sent in case the username was
   correct".
3. In the server-side if the user exists Generate **a new random GUID** that is attached to this User and has a certain time-span for example (1 hour).
4. After generating this GUID send an email with a link to this User. It could look like `https://website.com/ResetPassword?token=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`
5. In the loading of ResetPassword.aspx check if:

   - The token is correct.
   - The token is still valid.

   If either of them wasn't true show him a message of an Invalid token and **don't proceed further**.
6. The User will fill-out the New Password and The reset password textboxes and in the server-side you using the provided Token get the corresponding user object and update the password with the new hash-salted version of it.
7. After a successful password-reset the current user-session (if exists) has to be invalidated and he has to be redirected to the login-page.

And of course all these transaction must be logged and also the user has to be notified that his password was changed.

P.S If you're using **ASP.Net Authorization** you will need to specificly allow access to this page

```
<location path="ResetPassword.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Also Refer to **OWASP Forget Password Cheatsheet**:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Forgot_Password_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Simple enough .. keep it up!

Comment: i used the same but without this part "An email will be sent in case the username was correct". :D

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to set `HttpContext.Current.SkipAuthorization` property to true in global application(`Global.asax`)

You can write code like this

```
string Url = Request.RawUrl; 
string TestUrl = Url.Split('&')[0];
string SessionData = Session["Authenticate"].ToString();
if (TestUrl.EndsWith("User_EditPassword.aspx?accesstype=email"))
{
    HttpContext.Current.SkipAuthorization = true;
}
```